# Как реализовать сортировку товаров?

Tags: django, веб-программирование

Реализую свой интернет-магазин на django, застрял на вопросе, как реализовать обновление списка товаров без обновления страницы. Пример - есть список товаров отсортированный на веб-странице по имени, есть кнопка, выполняющая функцию сортировки по цене. Как реализовать работу так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки обновление всей страницы не происходило, а только списка товаров на этой странице.
Пример - сайт Lamoda, при выборе действия обновляет только сортировку товаров (при этом не видно обновления страницы).

Comment: Вам нужно сделать запрос к вашему API с нужными настройками фильтра и получить товары, эти товары отрендерить.

Comment: @OliverPatterson а рендер не будет давать эффекта обновления страницы ?  Как я понял, вы предлагаете через context в рендере передавать отсортированные товары, это разве не даст эффекта обновления страницы?

Answer (score 0):

Lamoda это SPA сделанный на фреймворке Vue и поддерживает динамическую загрузку данных на страницу без обновления страницы.

Так как вы делаете сайт на django и если я правильно понял без drf, то вы никак не сделаете сортировку без обновления страницы.

Вы можете сделать ручку которая будет отдавать список товаров в формате JSON с сортировкой и обращаться через JavaScript для получения товаров и отображения на сайте.